# Ag- grid button click doesnt work inside cell

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, ag-grid

I demonstrated my real world big project with this tiny stackblitz example.I have ag-grid and all columns are clickable via `(cellClicked)="onCellClicked($event)"`

```
<div style="width: 400px;">
    <ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 200px;" class="ag-theme-fresh"
        (cellClicked)="onCellClicked($event)" [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [suppressRowClickSelection]="true">
    </ag-grid-angular>
</div>
  onCellClicked(params) {
    alert("Cell clicked");
  }
```

I also inserted buttons on last column with `buttonRenderer` like below

```
 {
        headerName: "Assign buttons",
        width: 100,
        cellRenderer: this.buttonRenderer
      }

  buttonRenderer(params) {
    return "<button (click)='assign()'>Assign me</button>";
  }
  assign() {
    alert("Assigned");
  }
```

After all these configuration grid looks like below

[image]

Here problem is when buttons on Assign column clicked, method `assign()` never triggered. Always `onCellClicked()` triggered and prints "Cell clicked". I went through ag-grid docs and found `suppressRowClickSelection` but didn't work for me. Also gave stopPropagation to button but didn't work either. How can I trigger clicked button's method `assign()` when clicked?

Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-3ctzvo?file=app%2Fmy-grid-application%2Fmy-grid-application.component.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't quite implemented your button correctly. You can't pass a function  `cellRenderer`, you must pass a component that implements the `ICellRendererAngularComp` interface. So you'll need to create your own custom cell renderer for the button.

Something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-button-renderer',
  template: `
    <button type="button" (click)="onClick($event)">{{label}}</button>
    `
})

export class ButtonRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {

  params;
  label: string;

  agInit(params): void {
    this.params = params;
    this.label = this.params.label || null;
  }

  refresh(params?: any): boolean {
    return true;
  }

  onClick($event) {
    if (this.params.onClick instanceof Function) {
      // put anything into params u want pass into parents component
      const params = {
        event: $event,
        rowData: this.params.node.data
        // ...something
      }
      this.params.onClick(this.params);

    }
  }
}
```

And the params you'll need to this component will be your `assign` function to tell the button what to call when the button is pressed and the button label:

```
headerName: "Assign buttons",
width: 100,
cellRenderer: "buttonRenderer",
cellRendererParams: {
  onClick: this.assign.bind(this),
  label: "Click"
}
```

Lastly, you'll need to tell the grid about this button by passing in the `frameworkComponents`  param like so:

```
  frameworkComponents = {
      buttonRenderer: ButtonRendererComponent,
    }
```

and in your html:

```
[frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-gxrszm?file=app/my-grid-application/my-grid-application.component.html) is a demo.

Comment: How would you do this so that the label text is dynamic rather than always showing 'Click'?  I've made numerous edits to that Demo without success.